# how to use formatdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

i found this in full calendar documentation:

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] ) -> String
```

the format i want my date in is `dd-MM-yyyy`.

can someone tell me how to correctly write this piece of code?

thanks :)

Comment: jQuery FullCalender, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myFormattedDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(myDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Format of 'formatString' outlined @ http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/.